# Rails BDD with Cucumber: no such file to load -- cucumber-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd

I have project on Rails (2.3.5). I add into environment.rb same sting:

config.gem "cucumber-rails",

run "rake gems:unpack:dependencies". Output of "rake gems":

- [F] cucumber-rails

  - [F] cucumber >= 0.6.2

    - [F] term-ansicolor >= 1.0.4
    - [F] treetop >= 1.4.2

      - [F] polyglot >= 0.3.1
    - [F] polyglot >= 0.2.9
    - [F] builder >= 2.1.2
    - [F] diff-lcs >= 1.1.2
    - [F] json_pure >= 1.2.0

When I run "script/generate cucumber" I get 
 Missing these required gems:
  cucumber-rails

Who can help me to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the `config.gem` statement from `environment.rb` to `environments/test.rb`

**EDIT**

Why does this work? I'm not sure, but my guess would be that the cucumber generator (`script/generate cucumber`) is expecting to run in the development environment, and not the test environment. When you declare `config.gem` in `environment.rb`, it applies to *all* environments. Maybe the generator gets confused when it finds `cucumber-rails` where it's not expected?

I'd go on, but my wrists are sore from all this hand-waving...

Comment: Do you know how can I define language global for all features?